# Find maximum value for each group and retrieve associated value from another column

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Please see sample data in attached picture.
I need to extract a list of Dept for all maximum values in CountOfDocs, for each unique MatterNumber.

So basically, given the data in the picture, my list should look like this:

```
000054 LIT
00006 BANKR
00007 NONE
00008 NONE
00009 BANKR
0001 BANKR
```

I played around with subtotals and pivot tables.  I'm using Excel 2010, so I don't have the option to display distinct values in the pivot table...  :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are fancy ways to do this, but it's always handy when you can knock out a simple solution.  Here's an approach you can use for problems of this type.  You were on the right track with a pivot table.  You can use the pivot table for the heavy lifting of identifying the targets, then do a lookup based on the results.  It's two steps, but it won't make your brain hurt.

You're only using the last three columns for this task, so I didn't include the Office column in my example.

[image]

Column D is a helper column to simplify the lookup.  You can hide that if you don't want to see it.  The counts aren't unique, so I combined them with the MatterNumber.  I stuck a period between them to ensure uniqueness.  That formula was just:

```
=A2 & "." & C2
```

(My example starts with MatterNumber in column A.)  The ampersands concatenate the pieces.

You're already working with pivot tables, so I won't go into detail on how to do it.  MatterNumber goes in the Rows window, and Count gets aggregated with Max.

To get the Dept name associated with each maximum count, lookup against the helper column to find the Dept name:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$19,MATCH(A23&"."&B23,$D$2:$D$19,0))
```

In my example, column B is Dept, which INDEX retrieves.  MATCH looks in the helper column for an exact match with its own concatenated target value (MatterNumber.Max_Count).

Note that the pivot table sorts the results based on the Rows values.  Also note that if there is a tie for maximum within a MatterNumber, this will retrieve just the first one.

If you don't want to see the Max-Count column of the pivot table, just position the pivot table so you can hide that column.